# Importing a .tsv file

Tags: r

I am having trouble importing a `.tsv` file in R. The data file is from Eurostats, and is publicly available: http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/en/web/products-datasets/-/MIGR_IMM10CTB

I use the below code to import it:

```
immig <- read.table(file="immig.tsv", sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```

However, the code does not seem to work. I do not receive any error messages, but the output looks like this:

```
> immig[1:3, 1:3]
   age.agedef.c_birth.unit.sex.geo.time X2015 X2014
1 TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,AT 4723  4093 
2 TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,BE 1017   953 
3 TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,BG  559   577
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to use `sep=","` instead, but it seems to solve some problems while creating others.

Comment: The table you are referring to is not a text file with tab separated values ...

Comment: download the file in a useable format here: http://appsso.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/nui/setupDownloads.do

Comment: The page says "Session invalid!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the problem that you are missing the 2013 data?

I downloaded the file at that link, unzipped it using a command line tool, and then it can be imported just fine using the readr library:

```r
library(readr)

immigration <- read_tsv("~/Downloads/migr_imm10ctb.tsv", na = ":")
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   `age,agedef,c_birth,unit,sex,geo\time` = col_character(),
#>   `2015` = col_character(),
#>   `2014` = col_character(),
#>   `2013` = col_character()
#> )

immigration
#> # A tibble: 45,558 x 4
#>    `age,agedef,c_birth,unit,sex,geo\\time` `2015` `2014` `2013`
#>                                      <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#>  1   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,AT   4723   4093   4085
#>  2   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,BE   1017    953   1035
#>  3   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,BG    559    577  743 p
#>  4   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,CH   2876   2766   2758
#>  5   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,CY   <NA>   <NA>     54
#>  6   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,CZ    120    106    155
#>  7   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,DE   <NA>   <NA>  14984
#>  8   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,DK    372    365    405
#>  9   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,EE     23      7     16
#> 10   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,EL   <NA>   <NA>    234
#> # ... with 45,548 more rows
```

Looks like there are some spare characters floating around (`743 p`) where there should only be numbers, so you'll need to do more cleaning and then convert to numeric.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

immigration %>%
    mutate_at(vars(`2015`:`2013`), str_extract, pattern = "[0-9]+") %>%
    mutate_at(vars(`2015`:`2013`), as.numeric)
#> # A tibble: 45,558 x 4
#>    `age,agedef,c_birth,unit,sex,geo\\time` `2015` `2014` `2013`
#>                                      <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,AT   4723   4093   4085
#>  2   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,BE   1017    953   1035
#>  3   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,BG    559    577    743
#>  4   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,CH   2876   2766   2758
#>  5   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,CY     NA     NA     54
#>  6   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,CZ    120    106    155
#>  7   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,DE     NA     NA  14984
#>  8   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,DK    372    365    405
#>  9   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,EE     23      7     16
#> 10   TOTAL,COMPLET,CC5_13_FOR_X_IS,NR,F,EL     NA     NA    234
#> # ... with 45,548 more rows
```

It's a tab-delimited file, but that first column is all put together with commas, so if what you are wanting is that information separated out, you could do that with `tidyr::separate()`.

```r
library(tidyr)

immigration %>%
    separate(`age,agedef,c_birth,unit,sex,geo\\time`,
             c("age", "agedef", "c_birth", "unit", "sex", "geo"),
             sep = ",")
#> # A tibble: 45,558 x 9
#>      age  agedef         c_birth  unit   sex   geo `2015` `2014` `2013`
#>  * <chr>   <chr>           <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#>  1 TOTAL COMPLET CC5_13_FOR_X_IS    NR     F    AT   4723   4093   4085
#>  2 TOTAL COMPLET CC5_13_FOR_X_IS    NR     F    BE   1017    953   1035
#>  3 TOTAL COMPLET CC5_13_FOR_X_IS    NR     F    BG    559    577  743 p
#>  4 TOTAL COMPLET CC5_13_FOR_X_IS    NR     F    CH   2876   2766   2758
#>  5 TOTAL COMPLET CC5_13_FOR_X_IS    NR     F    CY   <NA>   <NA>     54
#>  6 TOTAL COMPLET CC5_13_FOR_X_IS    NR     F    CZ    120    106    155
#>  7 TOTAL COMPLET CC5_13_FOR_X_IS    NR     F    DE   <NA>   <NA>  14984
#>  8 TOTAL COMPLET CC5_13_FOR_X_IS    NR     F    DK    372    365    405
#>  9 TOTAL COMPLET CC5_13_FOR_X_IS    NR     F    EE     23      7     16
#> 10 TOTAL COMPLET CC5_13_FOR_X_IS    NR     F    EL   <NA>   <NA>    234
#> # ... with 45,548 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this could be a starting point:

```
link <- "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?file=data/migr_imm10ctb.tsv.gz"

data <- readr::read_csv(link) %>% 
       separate("geo\\time\t2015 \t2014 \t2013", into = c("geo", "2015", "2014", "2013"), sep = "\t")
```